# Identity DB context / hint no plural tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have an existing DB context that worked well so far with EF configuration as below

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Configure Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention 
            // If you keep this convention then the generated tables will have pluralized names. 
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();
}
```

I followed an [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/) to extend the Identity model provided by MVC to link to a person in my existing DB Context.

App User

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}

public virtual Person LinkedPerson { get; set; }//My reference to existing person definition
```

}

Context

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    }
```

The app works as long as I dont use the register or login function. However once I have registered as an user all my models are now duplicated, one as singular the other as a pluralized form of that.

Where could I tell the MVC identity framework not to recreate pluralized tables and use the existing (Singular) db objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` doesn't work for Identity tables. So it is needed to resolve explicitly:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Configure Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention 
        // If you keep this convention then the generated tables will have pluralized names. 
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRole");             
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUser");

    }
```

Comment: thank you. I have explicitly stated and it works as desired.+1